# How to clear Meteor's user even offline

Tags: meteor, logout, meteor-accounts

I don't know why, the logout button in my Meteor App often fails to callback. the code is simple:

```js
$scope.logout = function () {
    Accounts.logout(function () {
        // the code often fails to come here
        $state.go('login');
    });
}
```

maybe the network's problem? so I added some code to ensure my logout button won't look like frozen:

```js
$scope.logout = function () {
    Accounts.logout(function () {
        // the code often fails to come here
        $state.go('login');
    });

    $timeout(function () {
        $state.go('login');
    }, 2000);
}
```

The redirection to login page succeeded, but because Meteor.userId() still have value, the login page still shows the App user someone is logged on.

I want to know if there is a way to delete Meteor.userId / Meteor.user family even when failed connecting to the server.

I know it is not a complete solution, the App user will probably failed to do the next login at that state, but at least they won't complain the App even cannot logout.

Comment: It's `Meteor.logout()` not `Accounts.logout()`

Comment: @MichelFloyd You should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @Michel Floyd  I remember I have tried both Meteor.logout and Accounts.logout and believed that there was no difference between them. But I will try again to confirm. thank you

Answer (score 0):

The function you're looking for is `Meteor.logout()` not `Accounts.logout()`